# Django does not create migration to create index for legacy Foreign Key field

Tags: django

I have a legacy table that does *not* have an index on the foreign key field in a PostgreSQL database. According to the docs Django [automatically creates an index for foreign key fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

I would like to add an index on this field. When I specify `db_index=True` on the foreign key field and run `makemigrations` it reports:

> No changes detected

Example:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    ...
    group_id = models.ForeignKey(Group, models.DO_NOTHING, db_index=True)  # added `db_index=True` here
```

Is there a way to get django to create a migration to create an index for this field?

Comment: That is true, but it does not need to create a migration for most databases. Most databases automatically create an index for all `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.

Comment: In MySQL you can check the indexes with `SHOW INDEX FROM table_name FROM db_name;`, Likely other database backends will have similar queries.

Comment: If your model has however `managed = False`. *You* are responsible to manage the table at the database side. So then Django will skip any changes in the models. It thus means you have to create an index yourself.

Comment: Thanks for replying @WillemVanOnsem. This table was originally created outside of Django and is now a managed table. For whatever reason an index was not originally created with the foreign key when the table was created. Now that it is managed by Django I would like to track this change in a migration.